# Crontab /etc/profile.d

Tags: linux, cron, profile

I have a crontab script which runs fine from the interactive shell.
However when running from crontab it fails because it doesnt run the scripts in /etc/profile.d/ (e.g. /etc/profile.d/java.sh)

Whats the best way of fixing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

begin the shell script with:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
```

This causes bash to start as a login shell, which means it will read /etc/profile and ~/.bash_profile.

Comment: Not really sure if this is a good idea or not?

Comment: To use this idea in SLES, had to specify `11 11 * * * /bin/bash -l -exec "some && commands"` right in crontab.

Answer (score 3):

Set SHELL on your crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
* * * * * # your_job
```